Why doesn't the Hochschild cohomology admit functoriality for every functor?
I'm reading about Alex Perry's paper The integral Hodge conjecture for two-dimensional Calabi–Yau categories. I'm confused about why the Hochschild cohomology is only functorial for functors (between linear categories) that are fully faithful.
Is there a digression for this phenomenon?

How would you associate a map of Hochschild cohomology with a general functor?

Hochschild cohomology is derived endomorphisms of the identity functor. If you have a random functor $f:C\to D$ and an endomorphism of $id_D$ (or $id_C$), how do you associate to that an endomorphism of $id_C$ (or $id_D$) ?
Clearly if $f$ is (derived) fully faithful, you can, by restriction; and if $f$ is a (derived) localization, you also can (though this time in a covariant way); but if $f$ is arbitrary, it's unclear what you might even want to do
